# Problems installing Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows XP

Tags: 12.04

I have been trying to install Ubuntu for the last few days, but somehow it doesn't work. During the installation I keep getting this message:

```
BusyBox v1.18.5 (ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu 4.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Comment: Downvote: Not enough information to be able to help. Anyway check: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162078#162078

Comment: Dito: Please edit your question to add information about the hardware you are running on. Give more details about what happens when you try to install.

Answer (score 0):

This means the graphical system could not be booted. Maybe the graphics card is not supported. We need more details to help you. What is your hardware and what did you do so far?
You can edit your question to add more specifics.